# Testing on restricted users

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2013, mstest

I am using visual Studio 2013 test agents and controllers to do testing on the end environment. The end environment is composed of a single virtual machine running Windows 7 with a user that has very little privileges (most of them are blocked using group policy). Is there a way to run a test agent on that user in order to have the closest testing environment as possible?
The restricted user is not part of a domain and of course does not have admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to run Test Agent if your Test User does not have appropriate priveleges.
You can try to run Test Agent as Administrator.

Comment: Doesn't having to change the testing environment defeats the purpose of testing using test agents on dedicated machines? Isn't there a way to get  as close as possible to the end environment (the restricted one)?

Comment: Running Test Agent as Admin is the closest thing you can do to achieve real environment.